# bootstrap tooltip not working right after upgrading jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I was using an older version of dataTables with bootstrap tooltip, and it worked fine.  After upgrading to dataTables 1.9, the content of the tooltip is injected directly into the TH that was supposed to have the tooltip applied on hover.  I don't see the original TH content - I see the tooltip content  The tooltip content shows up normal in the pop up tool tip when I over over the TH.

In order to comply with our coding standards, I need to use the bootstrap tooltip and not the newer dataTables tooltip which I think may be what is causing me the issue.

```
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="seo mapping tool tip 1" class="col-sm-1">Mapping</th>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="analytics tool tip 2" class="col-sm-1">Analytics Title Variable</th>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="seo title content tooltip 3" class="col-sm-1">Analytics Title Content</th>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="meta title variable tooltip 4" class="col-sm-1">Meta Title Variable</th>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="meta title content variable tooltip 5" class="col-sm-1">meta title content</th>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="seo meta description tool tip 6" class="col-sm-1">meta description</th>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="seo meta description content tool tip 7" class="col-sm-1">meta description content</th>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="seo meta keyword tool tip 8" class="col-sm-1">meta keyword</th>
    <th data-role="tooltip" data-title="seo meta keyword content tool tip 9" class="col-sm-1">meta keyword content</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>some mapping</td>
      <td>analytics title variable</td>
      <td>analytics title content</td>
      <td>meta title variable</td>
      <td>meta title content</td>
      <td>meta description variable</td>
      <td>meta description content</td>
      <td>meta keywords</td>
      <td>meta keywords content</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>

<!-- snipped -->
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $("th").tooltip({
    container: 'body'
  });
 });

</script>
```

I tried this

```
$('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});
```

it had no effect.

Comment: I see no `data-toggle` attribute on your table headers, what if you change to: `$('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-role="tooltip"]'});` ?

Comment: I tried this just before I read your email.  Made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried creating a fiddle on jsfiddle or through SO so that other's may try to assist you?

Answer (score 0):

I have something that works ... still don't know why the problem occurs, but I found a workaround:

I added a data-content with the text I want to go in each TH.  Then I added a drawCallback function to my dataTable

```
 $(".seoReport").DataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
     $(".seoReport th").each(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).data("content"));
     })
    }
  });
```

This solves the problem ... a bit of a hack.  Open to suggestions how to prevent the tooltip from highjacking that TH in the first place.